# Is it possible to create own node js module and publishing it on private server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

It it possible to create my own node module so that i could type
-npm install test
in my console and that the module is loading from private server?

I know i can write my own module and publishing it on npmjs.org, but is there a way for a private node server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a private server. If you execute `npm i` inside the directory of some module, it will install it.

Alternatively, you can install a module using the following syntax `npm i <path to module directory>` (f.e. `npm i c:\private_modules\mymodule`).

If the above approach is enough for you, maybe you should take a look at [sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia).

Comment: ah ok thanks! but what if i want to publish it with others so that the directory is not on my machine?

Comment: @mk2015 What about a shared folder in your network? ;)

Comment: that should work yes! :D 
sorry for that stupid question :D

Answer (score 0):

Beside using the installation, when you are developing other private module it is easier in development mode use the `npm link` approach.

- Go into `my-private` project.
- `npm link` - create a link
- Now go to other project A which depends of the `my-private` module, create a link  `npm link my-private`

You can now check with `npm ls` if the link exists.

Comment: sinopia is a great module to share node modules private i guess